# What structures are sometimes used in your country? -> What +sth + verb question format

Tags: grammar, questions, questions-v-relatives

1. > What structures are sometimes used in your country?
   >   or
   >   What are structures sometimes used in your country?
2. > What tax issues arise in your jurisdiction?
   >   or
   >   What do tax issues arise in your jurisdiction?
   >   or
   >   What tax issues do arise in your jurisdiction?

Are these in the correct question format? If not, how should I fix it?

My previous question was put on hold, so let me rephrase my question. 
I learned that in question forms I need to put verbs first and then put subjects, right? i.e., what time *do* you go to church?  However, I'm not sure what to do with the above-mentioned sentences.

Comment: The correct process when your question is put on hold is to edit that question and let it go through the "reopen" process, not to post a duplicate question. I've deleted your previous question, but in the future, please edit the existing one. That will automatically put it in the queue to be reopened. (Your previous question already had 3 votes to reopen)

Comment: The [Details Please](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/q/439/) post on [meta] has some advice for avoiding "show your research/needs more context" close votes that might be helpful. In general, just explaining what you already know and why that doesn't help answer your question is enough. The goal is to help folks write good answers, and it doesn't help you if they repeat stuff you already know.

Answer (score 1):

You might find this page helpful:  [Subject and Object Questions in English](https://www.espressoenglish.net/subject-and-object-questions-in-english/)

These are called *subject questions* and do not require the "do" helping verb, nor do you have to invert the word order.

> What structures are used in your country?
>
> What tax issues arise in your jurisdiction?

etc.